# Is Owned<T> lazy loading in Autofac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I am deciding to use `Func<Owned<INotificationService>>` in order to perform notification work in another `Task` inside action in `ASP.MVC`. But I don't use `INotificationService` often so I like to make it lazy loading but I was not sure if `Func<Owned<T>>` support somehow lazy loading by default or I need to wrap it in `Laz<>` syntax like below:

```
private readonly Lazy<Func<Owned<INotificationService>>> _notificationService;
```

This might work ok but getting it's value would be not a bit difficult to understand by the other.

```
_notificationService.Value().Value.... etc
```

Comment: `Owned<T>` is not related to lazy loading.  It just means you are responsible for releasing the owned object.

Comment: @Amy so the only way to make it lazy loading is to wrap it with lazy syntax ?

Comment: `Lazy<T>` or `Func<T>`, yes.